# Что делать, если выдаёт проблему при компиляции простого .cpp файла в vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, компиляция

Установил mingw32 на свою windows 7, добавил путь в PATH, перезагрузил комп, установил Visual Studio Community 2019, перезагрузил комп, установил VS Code 1.70.2, перезагрузил комп, установил в VS Code расширение C/C++ от Microsoft.
Создал папку, открыл в VS Code, создал main.cpp, написал в него следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    bool result = true;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Ошибок не выдало, открыл run task, выбрал C/C++: g++.exe сборка активного файла, выдало следующий текст:

```
Запуск сборки…
C:/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\Данил\Desktop\whatever\main.cpp -o C:\Users\Данил\Desktop\whatever\main.exe 
"cmd" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

Сборка завершена с ошибками.

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

.vscode\settings.json выглядит вот так:
`{ "files.associations": { "ostream": "cpp" } }`

PATH выглядит вот так:

```
c:\mingw32\bin;c:\mingw32\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\11.3.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;PATH;C:\Program Files\Process Lasso\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

Comment: Можно удалить VS Code 1.70.2, mingw32 и использовать обычную Visual Studio.

Comment: Можно удалить Windows и поставить Linux.

Comment: Да просто запустите компиляцию руками. Для этого не нужна IDE. Батник облегчит жизнь. Пока нет больших проектов, можно текстовым редактором пользоваться с подсветкой синтакисса просто.

Comment: Для плюсов советую всё таки Qt Creator использовать

Comment: Покажите содержимое `tasks.json`.

Answer (score 0):

**Ошибка может возникать из-за того, **что вы уже открыли** **`.exe`** **файл, из-за чего при повторной компиляции того же файла при его перезаписи (замене)** случается ошибка из-за того, что файл уже открыт и используется.**

И да, лучше использовать `Visual Studio` для больших проектов.

Comment: Лучше использовать Qt Creator для C++.